# AngularJS: How can I share data across controller?

Tags: angularjs

I want to get title dynamically. How do I share the $scope.title in indexCtrl?

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.title = 'OneFC';
})

app.controller('secondCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.title = 'UFC';
})

app.controller('indexCtrl', function(){
    // i want to get the title here depends on the active state in ui-router.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have some ways to do this. rootscope's property can handle this which is same as global var in your app. But I love OOP and  I think we should encapsulate the processing of data in a service.

Code for service:

```
app.factory('titleFactory',function(){
    var _title = null;
    return {
       setTitle: function(title) {
          this._title = title;
       },

       getTitle: function() {
            return this._title;
       }
  }
});
```

Now in any controller you just need inject and call get or set title to handle your data.

Set title value (same for secondCtrl):

```
app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope,titleFactory){
      titleFactory.setTitle('OneFC');
})
```

Title now can be accessed by all other controllers like this:

```
app.controller('indexCtrl', function(){
     $scope.title = titleFactory.getTitle();
});
```

Comment: Tried it but no luck.

Comment: Up your code to plunkr so we can see why you get 'no luck'

Comment: see here for read and write title https://plnkr.co/edit/4JjnSEww5oSMl3ZKXmKH?p=preview

Comment: mark answer as 'accepted' if you see it fit your expectation and someone can know how to do with your problem in the future

Answer (score 0):

try to use `$rootScope.title`?

```
app.controller('indexCtrl', ['$rootScope','$scope',function($rootScope, $scope){
    $rootScope.$on("toindexCtrl", function (e) {
       $scope.$apply(function () {
          $scope.title = $rootScope.title;
      });
   });
}])

app.controller('secondCtrl', ['$rootScope','$scope', function($rootScope, $scope){
    $rootScope.title = 'UFC';
    $rootScope.$broadcast('toindexCtrl');
}])
```

This code work for me. I also use $broadcast to listen when the value changed.

Comment: included rootScope at header? something like: 
app.controller('secondCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', function($rootScope, $scope){ $rootScope.title = 'UFC'; $rootScope.$broadcast('toindexCtrl'); }])

Comment: Yes I already did it when I tried it. Wait. I'll create a fiddle for this one.

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend passing it as Data inside your routes definitions (you can do that in case you were not aware of) just like this:

```
$stateProvider.state("page1", {
    url: "/page1",
    data: {
        title: "Your Title Here"
    },
    views: {
    }
}).state("page2", {
    url: "/page2",
    data: {
        title: "Your Other Title Here"
    },
    views: {

    }
})
```

Afterwards, you can use it in your controller like this:

```
app.controller('indexCtrl', function($state){ //Note that you inject state
    $scope.pageTitle= $state.data.title;
}
```

Hope this works for you

Regards

Comment: $stateProvider
    .state('companyData', {
        url: '/dashboard/companyData',
        templateUrl: 'html/companydata.html',
        data: {
            title: 'Company Data'
        },
        controller: 'companyDataCtrl'
});

TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined